# HTML/CSS Table with a variable row height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
 ---------- ----------
|          |          |
|  header  |  header  |
|          |          |
 ---------- ----------
|          |          |
|  ......  |  ......  |
|          |          |
 ---------- ----------





---- bottom of parent ----
```

I want the height of the `<tr>` to have a maximum value, and I want height of the `<table>` to have a maximum value, so the height of the `<tr>` should be able to shrink so that I can get this result:

```
 ---------- ----------
|  header  |  header  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
|  ......  |  ......  |
 ---------- ----------
---- bottom of parent ----
```

However, I also don't want to end up with a result like this:

```
 ---------- ----------
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|  header  |  header  |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
 ---------- ----------
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|  ......  |  ......  |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
|          |          |
 ---------- ----------
---- bottom of parent ----
```

Which is what I'm getting with my code.

I tried playing around with `min-height`, `max-height`, `height`, etc. but there does't seem to be a solution so far.

```
<style>
  table { height: 400px }
  tr    { /* don't know what to put here */ }
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th><th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <...>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I know I probably can solve this simply by adding a wrapper and setting a `max-height` of 100% to the table, but the code I'm working with is generating tables using some script and I can't add a `<div>` at my heart's content.

Also, I have to specify that I have a maximum amount of 20 rows possible (which is often used up entirely and paginated since there's a lot of data), and I need to have the height of the table to be a specific size when there are 20 rows used, but in some cases, less than 20 rows are needed, and when this happens, the height of the rows become stretched. It becomes absurdly stretched when there's only 1 row.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the table height to be exactly 400px, or do you want it to stretch to 100% of its parent height?

Answer (score 0):

Reading this could help you:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

And why don't you set the height of the table rows using "padding-top" and "padding-bottom"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want the table to expand to 100% of its parent height, up to a maximum value.

I think I've got it: http://jsfiddle.net/xs65gev7/1/

```
.parent { height:100vh; border:1px solid green; }
.table { height:100%; max-height:400px; border:1px solid red; }
.cell { border:1px blue solid; }
```

I used 100vh for the parent to expand it to the window height, so you can resize the window to experiment with the table behavior. The table has height:100% and max-height:400px, which I believe accomplishes what you want.

Regarding the inability to add a div as the parent, you need to use whatever is the parent (or an ancestor) of the table to set the enclosing height. *Something* must limit the height of the table if it's going to shrink below its fixed max-height.